# With Antenna House 6.3 XSL processor, how can border's be made to appear when a row breaks across pages?

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

With Antenna House 6.3 XSL processor, how can border's be made to appear when a row breaks across pages?

My fo looks like:

```
<fo:table xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" border-bottom-color="black"
    border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-left-color="black"
    border-left-style="solid" border-left-width="0.5pt" border-right-color="black"
    border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt" border-top-color="black"
    border-top-style="solid" border-top-width="0.5pt" font-size="7pt" space-after="10pt"
    space-before="10pt" start-indent="inherit" width="auto">
    <fo:table-body start-indent="0pt" table-layout="auto">
        <fo:table-row keep-together="always">
            <fo:table-cell border-after-width.conditionality="retain" border-bottom-color="black"
                border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt" border-right-color="black"
                border-right-style="solid" border-right-width="0.5pt">
                <fo:block end-indent="4pt" space-after="3pt" space-after.conditionality="retain"
                    space-before="4pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="4pt"
                    >This</fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border-after-width.conditionality="retain" border-bottom-color="black"
                border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.5pt">
                <fo:block end-indent="4pt" space-after="3pt" space-after.conditionality="retain"
                    space-before="4pt" space-before.conditionality="retain" start-indent="4pt">
                    <fo:block background-color="#f0f0f0" end-indent="from-parent(end-indent)"
                        font-size="88.88888889%" keep-with-previous.within-page="always"
                        line-height="106%" linefeed-treatment="preserve" padding="6pt"
                        space-after="0pt" space-before="9pt"
                        start-indent="from-parent(start-indent)" white-space-collapse="false"
                        white-space-treatment="preserve" wrap-option="wrap"
                        line-height-shift-adjustment="disregard-shifts" font-family="Courier New"
                        >That</fo:block>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

The result is that there is no bottom border or top border when a row breaks across a page.

I can't post unless I add more details, apparently.

When a document renders and a table has a row that breaks across the page, no border appears at the bottom of the page where it broke, and no border appears at the top of the page where it broke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `border-before-width.conditionality="retain"` to `fo:table` will solve your problem. See following sample snap-shot modfied from your sample FO file.

[image: Sample PDF snap-shot]

Comment: Thank you! I added border-after-width.conditionality="retain" to fo:table, also. Without that the border only appeared at the top of the page.

Comment: Hi @toshihiko, Is there a way to have a different cell border bottom style if the cell breaks across a page boundary? See my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71620898/make-cell-bottom-border-style-visible-but-different-from-tables-default-bottom